# Requiring unknown module "socket.io-client/socket.io"

Tags: socket.io, react-native

I did `npm install socket.io-client`.
I then import it as shown below

```js
import React from 'react-native';
import './UserAgent';

import io from 'socket.io-client/socket.io';
```

But when I run my app, I get the following error:

> Requiring uknown module "socket.io-client/socket.io". If you are sure
>   this module is there, try restarting the packager.

I tried installing again and updating from npm.

I restarted the packager like 1000 times.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same issue and I found solution.

Change code from

```
import io from 'socket.io-client/socket.io';
```

to

```
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';
```

Try add **dist** directory.

I had same issue a couple of days ago and resolved it below reference.

reference:
https://github.com/reactotron/reactotron/pull/280/commits/d8725351e80093edc4bcfb65d6389a9ba654ff37

Comment: I'm commenting as a StackOverflow (SO) reviewer because you're a new user. This looks like useful information but you can improve your answer in a couple of ways. (1) Your answer will exist on for many years and that link on github might disappear. For that reason it's important to tell readers the main things that the link says in case it does disappear. (2) Where should the **dist** directory be added?

Comment: Thanks a ton Suhan. I was stuck for a couple of days because of this issue. Changing the import statement solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

The module is `socket.io-client` so,

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that also. Both `socket.io-client` and `socket.io` throw the same error as well ...

Answer (score 0):

For everyone stuck on this, I managed to fix it by including the `socket.io.js` standalone file in my project and importing it from there.

For some reason the RN Packager does not build the dependency in `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that you will have issues importing SocketIO in this fashion, via import.

You can try switching to the require syntax and be sure to include the requisite userAgent line beforehand.

```js
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
let io = require('socket.io-client/socket.io');
```

I have a project which does the same thing which you can compare against, [React Native Messenger](https://github.com/adamterlson/react-native-messenger/blob/master/app/socket.js).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same code as you with no trouble.  Perhaps you need to upgrade your react-native?  I'm on the latest as of this writing: 0.18.0-rc.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
let io = require('../../node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');
```

Tried everything I could think of this is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Verify that socket io client is installed in node_modules dependency, if not try to reinstall the dependency. If it is there then you can update the statement

```
import io from 'socket.io-client/socket.io'
```

to

```
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'
```

It should work now.